# How is pthread_join implemented?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, scheduling

I'm a little new to threading, so you'll have to forgive the naiveté of this question.

How is `pthread_join` implemented and how does it effect thread scheduling?

I always pictured `pthread_join` implemented with a while loop, simply causing the calling thread to yield until the target thread completes. Like this (very approximate pseudocode):

```
atomic bool done;

thread_run {

    do_stuff();
    done = true;

}

thread_join {

    while(!done) {
        thread_yield();
    //  basically, make the thread that calls "join" on
    //  our thread yield until our thread completes
    }
}
```

Is this an accurate depiction, or am I vastly oversimplifying the process?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that's the general idea. For gory details of a particular implementation take a look at [glibc](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_join.c;h=6a87a8b329c3e34a57d65e86d45fa97a5fdb2fe2;hb=master).

Comment: The only really big difference between his code and the real code is that his code would cause the joining thread to burn 100% of the CPU if there's a spare core.

Answer (score 7):

pthread_join is probably internally implemented as a wait for a semaphore which is triggered when the thread exits, either when it calls pthread_exit or when its main function exits.

In any case, the source code for glibc is available, try google code search (I saw some informative stuff in there)

Comment: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_join.c;h=6a87a8b329c3e34a57d65e86d45fa97a5fdb2fe2;hb=master#l89 for the line where magic happens.

Answer (score 3):

A thread typically has a little structure associated with it, the thread context. That structure can be stuffed with all the pieces of data which are needed to make the thread "work".

For instance, the root of a data structure needed to access the thread-specific keys of that thread, and to iterate over them to clean them up when it is being shut down.

There is typically a mutex-like lock in that structure, and perhaps more than one for different sections.

The thread context can have a little field in it where a terminating thread can place its exit status. (The `void *` returned by `pthread_exit` or by returning from the thread function.)

The thread context can also indicate the thread's state (not yet created, running, stopped).

There may be a synchronization primitive, such as a condition variable or semaphore, which the thread can `kick`, after preparing the termination status and indicating that it is terminating.

The `pthread_join` function can wait on that synchronization primitive. Once the wait finishes, the function can trigger a resource clean up for that thread, in addition to pulling out the status.

The thread continues to execute after signaling the join. To do that it must continue to have a context with a stack. After that point, the system has to work out the problem of cleanly stopping the thread in the background.

A user-space implementation of threading can defer that to the kernel. E.g. some signal can go off or whatever indicating that a thread has finished. At that point, user space knows that the thread cannot possibly be using its stack any more and can recycle it.

In the kernel, the scheduler can "eat" a thread. The thread can call some function in the scheduler which never returns after cleaning up most of its resources. It marks the thread as dead and switches context to another thread. The thread's stack will never be used again (since that function never returns) and can be reclaimed, as well as its task structure and any remaining things attached to it.