# Code of the function pthread_join - Pthread Library

Tags: c, pthreads, pthread-join

I'm looking for the code of the pthread_join, but online I found only the [prototype](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html). Could you tell me where I can find it please?

Comment: Here is [an example](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_join.c;h=6a87a8b329c3e34a57d65e86d45fa97a5fdb2fe2;hb=master), which is linked from [linux - How is pthread_join implemented? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821881/how-is-pthread-join-implemented)

Comment: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/nptl/pthread_join.c

Comment: thank you a lot for your links!

Comment: [openbsd pthread_join](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libthr/thread/thr_join.c#L42)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not "the code", there are many different implementations that partially build on each other. For example

- [The GNU C Library if you are using gcc](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/nptl/pthread_create.c.html)
- [Google's implementation for Android](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/10ce969/libc/bionic/pthread.c)
- [Apple's implementation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libpthread/libpthread-301.50.1/src/pthread.c.auto.html)